# Accordion Menu issues

Tags: jquery

I have created a simple accordion menu.My problem is when i click "Folder1" it expands but when i click it back again it should collapse .. i'm stuck with that and not able to proceed any help..

JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nY2t7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#content >li').each(function(i){

        hideElements($(this));
    });

    $('#content').click(function(event) {

        $x = $(event.target);

        //check if the element is the root node if so then hide all other li's and reveal the current one
        if($x.parent().is('ul#content')) {

            if($x.is(':visible')) {     //check if its already expanded .. if so then collapse and return
                $x.find('ul >li').slideUp(300 , function() {
                    **//return;** does not work

                });
            }

            $('#content ul>li').each(function(i){                   
                    collapseElements($(this));
            });
        }


        if($x.is('li'))
            $x.find('ul:first > li').slideToggle(300);  



    });


    function collapseElements(el) {
        if(el.is(':visible')) {
            el.slideUp(300);
        }

    }

    function hideElements(elem) {
        elem.find('ul >li').hide(); 

        //$($e >li).hide(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code that works:

```
$('#content').click(function(event) {
  var $el = $(event.target);
  $el.find('ul:first > li').slideToggle(300);    
});
```

Although, It is stateless which is a bad thing.

Comment: thank you alexander but why doesn't calling return after animation doesn't work.. $x.find('ul >li').slideUp(300 , function() {
                    **//return;** does not work

                });

Comment: @user1184100, It does work. You are returning from `function(){}` though. Don't forget to mark as an answer.